# Правильное использование lifetime + Cow<', Path>

Tags: rust

**Требуется:** Передать Path конструктору структуры используя `Cow` и `Lifetime`.

**Проблема:**

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `path` because it is borrowed
   --> src/init/mod.rs:106:10
    |
94  |    let name = path.file_name();
    |               ---- borrow of `path` occurs here
...
106 |     path:path,
    |          ^^^^ move out of `path` occurs here
```

Компилятор думает что path должен умереть(также заимствоватся) на функции `path.file_name()`. Я хочу получить имя Path, и отдать его структуре.

**Пример кода:**

```
pub enum cluDaemonTypeFs<'a> {
    MODULE_DIR(Cow<'a, Path>),
    MODULE_FILE,
}


struct cluDaemon<'d> {
    type_path_fs:cluDaemonTypeFs<'d>,
    path:Cow<'d, Path>,

    //name:Cow<'d, str>,
    //init:&'d cluInit<'d>,
}

impl<'d> cluDaemon<'d> {
    pub fn open_path<'k>(path:Cow<'d, Path>) -> Result<cluDaemon<'d>, cluDaemonErr> {
        if path.is_file() {
            let name = path.file_name(); <<--- MOVE???
            /*let nn = path.clone();
            let name = match path.file_name() {
                Some(v) => v,
                None => {
                    return Err(cluDaemonErr::err_unknown_file_name(format!("{:?}", path)));
                }
            };*/


            return Ok(cluDaemon {
                type_path_fs:cluDaemonTypeFs::MODULE_FILE,
                path:path,
            });
```

**Пример вызывающего кода:**

```
pub fn add_daemon<'l>(&self, file:Cow<'init, Path>) -> Result<(), cluInitErr> {
        if let Ok(mut daemons_all_write) = self.daemons_all.write(){
            let daemon_open = match cluDaemon::open_path(file){
                Ok(e) => e,
                Err(e) => { return Ok(()); }//return Err(cluInitErr::err_daemon_open(e)); } 
            };
            daemons_all_write.push(daemon_open);
        }
        Ok(())
    }
```

Начело компилироватся только если использовать прямое копирование Cow<,Path>. Но если начать отдавать name структуре появляется path.file_name() { ^^^^ does not live long enough

```
return Ok(cluDaemon {
                type_path_fs:cluDaemonTypeFs::MODULE_FILE,
                path:path.clone(),
                //name:name.to_string_lossy(),
            });
```

Есть ли объяснение всему этому???

Comment: Замечания по стилю:
1) Префикс `clu` в именах типов, во-первых, нарушает конвенцию начинать имена типов с заглавных букв (на что у компилятора есть lint), во-вторых, выглядит так, будто он хочет стать именем модуля, содержащего типы с простыми и короткими именами `Daemon` и `DaemonTypeFs`, но отчего-то стесняется :)
2) Элементы типа-перечисления принято именовать в CamelCase.

Comment: да, знаю. компилятору не нравятся эти наименования:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без явной необходимости не стоит прошивать параметр времени жизни в тип данных. Это в-основном используется для типов, представляющих заимствованные значения: хитрые временные ссылки, RAII scope guards, итераторы и т.п.

Обычные долгоживущие `'static` типы могут содержать только "владеемые" данные, в данном случае это `PathBuf`:

```
struct Daemon {
    path: PathBuf
}
```

`Cow` предназначен для оптимизации в отдельных оправданных случаях; прописывание его в сигнатуры функций в явном виде лишает API гибкости в использовании и может даже замедлить доступ к значению. Полиморфизм над различными типами параметров, которые конвертируются в ссылку на `Path`, лучше сделать обобщением над типажом `AsRef<Path>`:

```
pub fn add_daemon<P: AsRef<Path>>(&self, file: P) -> Result<(), InitErr> {
    // ...
}
```

В параметр `file` здесь подойдет и `&Path`, и `&PathBuf`, и `Cow<'foo, Path>`, и даже обычный строковый литерал.

Comment: Спасибо за обьяснение.  но разве static не означает что переменная жива пока жива программа незааисимо от структуры?  А про намек на AsRef, спасибо!

Comment: Ключевое слово `static` (без апострофа) обозначает статические данные. В системе типов есть идентификатор времени жизни `'static`. Он означает, что возможные экземпляры не ограничены каким-либо меньшим, чем вся программа, временем жизни, хотя конкретные экземпляры могут быть короткоживущими. В определениях типов он не используется явно, но подразумевается, если содержимое типа не ограничено параметризованным временем жизни. Явно `'static` иногда используется в ограничениях параметрических типов обобщенных деклараций.

Comment: Уточнение к предыдущему: **как ограничение для обобщенных типовых параметров**, `'static` означает, что конкретные параметры-типы не должны быть ограничены каким-либо меньшим, чем вся программа, временем жизни, хотя экземпляры этих типов могут быть короткоживущими. В конкретном виде его можно увидеть в ссылочных типах `&'static`, где он означает, что значение под ссылкой действительно все время жизни программы.

Comment: Попробовал AsRef, пока никак...   path:AsRef<Path>,
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path> + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `std::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path> + 'static`
   = note: only the last field of a struct may have a dynamically sized type

Comment: В каком коде? У меня работает:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=64aa9af5674a7ae8dad50f77ad263372&version=stable